# Two-way synchronization between lists

Tags: c#

I hope someone here can help me with this problem that's been giving me a headache.

If I have two lists of custom objects, is there any way (using LINQ or otherwise) to performance-efficiently synchronize them? Performance matters because there could conceivably be a very large amount of objects in the lists.

I need to check for new or deleted items on one list - I assume here that one list is master and only allow **new** objects to be added there or objects to be outright deleted so this doesn't seem too hard.

But I also need to synchronize changes made to **either** list based on a timestamp (newest takes precedence).

Code example:

```
public class CalendarItem
{
    public CalendarItem(int id, string subject, string content, DateTime lastUpdated, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        Id = id;
        Subject = subject;
        Content = content;
        LastUpdated = lastUpdated;
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
    }

    public int Id { get; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; }
    public string Subject { get; }
    public string Content { get; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; }
}
```

Then I want to be able to do something like the following setup:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;

var itemIdentical1 = new CalendarItem(1, "Item Identical On Both Lists", "", time, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
var itemIdentical2 = new CalendarItem(1, "Item Identical On Both Lists", "", time, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);

var itemBeforeUpdate1 = new CalendarItem(2, "Item On List 1 Will Be Changed", "", time, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
var itemUpdated1 = new CalendarItem(2, "Item on List 1 Changed", "", time.AddMinutes(15), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);

var itemBeforeUpdate2 = new CalendarItem(3, "Item On List 2 Will Be Changed", "", time, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
var itemUpdated2 = new CalendarItem(3, "Item on List 2 Changed", "", time.AddMinutes(15), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);

var itemBeforeUpdate3 = new CalendarItem(4, "More Item On List 2 Will Be Changed", "", time, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
var itemUpdated3 = new CalendarItem(4, "More Item on List 2 Changed", "", time.AddMinutes(15), DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);

var list1 = new List<CalendarItem> { itemIdentical1, itemUpdated1, itemBeforeUpdate2, itemBeforeUpdate3 };
var list2 = new List<CalendarItem> { itemIdentical2, itemBeforeUpdate1, itemUpdated2, itemUpdated3 };
```

Then here we should have the magic step I'm missing in order to get the following:

```
var listOfItemsToUpdateOnList1 = List { itemUpdated2, itemUpdated3 };
var listOfItemsToUpdateOnList2 = List { itemUpdated1 };
```

Comment: This sounds very similar to the case of a Distributed Database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_database So any approaches from that area could help you. Maybe you could even move this to a distributed Database entirely?

Comment: Simple question:  Why not just have a single underlying list?  Maybe you can explain more about the problem rather than focusing on the solution.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith: Agreed, it does smell a bit like a XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Usually you only use distributed DB's because you can not effectively/reliable access the main DB. But if both Lists are in memory, how can there be such an issue?

Comment: The problem is that I have data coming in from two sources (which I do not control). I can abstract that data into the same class (by dropping some unnecessary fields) to allow me to compare and merge them like this, in order to display the most recent data to the user.

Comment: More specifically as my code alludes to we are dealing with calendar synchronization (in Outlook) and shared calendars. So I don't see how I can simplify the underlying problem.

Comment: Then how about joining them with LINQ? This is not disimilar to having to join two almsot identical tables in SQL. And LINQ is basically "SQL for any Collection in memory"

Comment: If it could be done with LINQ that would be great. But I've failed to do so, although that's probably just my mistakes. But I cannot find the right way to compare the lists with LINQ to get the desired output...